Trying to install node-cld fails with message "error C7626: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare ..."
(Please note that this is not a duplicate of Error C7626: Unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, since it is happening in an external library, which I cannot modify, and is machine-dependent.)
I'm trying to build this repo: https://github.com/FlameWolf/quip-api, and I get the below error when running npm install:
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm error cldutil.cc
npm error C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld\deps\cld\internal\scoreonescriptspan.h(117,16): error C7626: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes [C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld\build\deps\cld\cld-c.vcxproj]
npm error   (compiling source file '../../../deps/cld/internal/cldutil.cc')
npm error   
npm error C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld\deps\cld\internal\scoreonescriptspan.h(132,16): error C7626: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes [C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld\build\deps\cld\cld-c.vcxproj]
npm error   (compiling source file '../../../deps/cld/internal/cldutil.cc')
npm error   
npm error C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld\deps\cld\internal\scoreonescriptspan.h(186,16): error C7626: unnamed class used in typedef name cannot declare members other than non-static data members, member enumerations, or member classes [C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld\build\deps\cld\cld-c.vcxproj]
npm error   (compiling source file '../../../deps/cld/internal/cldutil.cc')
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.2.0
npm error gyp info using node@23.0.0 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.6 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm error (node:6376) ExperimentalWarning: Support for loading ES Module in require() is an experimental feature and might change at any time  
npm error (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm error gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.11.35327.3) found at:
npm error gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm error gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm error gyp info spawn C:\Python312\python.exe
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\******\\source\\repos\\quip-api\\node_modules\\cld\\build\\config.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\******\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\23.0.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\******\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\23.0.0',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\******\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\23.0.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\******\\source\\repos\\quip-api\\node_modules\\cld',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\******\\source\\repos\\quip-api\\node_modules\\cld\\build',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp info spawn C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args 'build\\binding.sln',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/nologo',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp ERR! build error
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:216:23)      
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:507:28)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\******\source\repos\quip-api\node_modules\cld
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v23.0.0
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.2.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-06T17_28_31_391Z-debug-0.log

Can anyone help with this?

This is regular problem with binary dep. You need to make sure you have a widespread platform that has prebuilt binary for it OR configured build tools. In your case you have node 23, never use odd versions without a reason. Try 22 or better 20 as it has a better chance. Then try npm i --build-from-source=false. I don't see if "cld" has prebuilt bins. If this doesn't help then try npm i -g --production windows-build-tools and try again. I'm not up to all-round answer and I don't see a dupe that would cover all the cases, but if this solves the problem, this would be the answer

@EstusFlask Thanks! Just downgrading to Node 20 did the trick, selected "install dev tools" tickbox in the wizard. (I tried Node 22 first but that didn't work.)
